# React useState() array mapping inside of component doesn't update if I don't scroll or click on browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tailwind-css, use-state

I've made this effect with React and Tailwind:

[GIF with the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na1Sq.gif)

As you can see, so far, so good. However, this effect just works when:

- I scroll on the browser
- I click on the browser
- I open the Chrome tools inspector

This is what happens when I do not do something of the above:

[GIF with the effect but not working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmD1Q.gif)

As you can see, that's not the effect I'm looking for.

So, apparently, there is a React render problem ocurring right here, and I'm stucked.

Inside, this works as follows:

```
const HomeHeader = () => {

    // This are imported images
    const IMAGES = [insta, twitter, netflix, mix];

    // This is an array that maps inside the component and renders the images as JSX
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let counter = 0;
        
        // An interval that creates a new element in the array "images" every 50 miliseconds
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setImages(prevState => [
                ...prevState,
                {
                    id: counter++,
                    duration: getRandom(5, 9) * 1000,
                    image: IMAGES[getRandom(0, IMAGES.length)],
                    height: getRandom(1, 6),
                    top: getRandom(0, window.innerHeight - window.innerHeight / 4),
                    right: getRandom(0, window.innerWidth)
                }
            ]);
        }, 50);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [])

    // Every time the state variable "images" is changed, add the cool animation to the last image and, when it ends, delete the image from the HTML
    useEffect(() => {
        if(images.length > 0) {
            let image = images[images.length - 1];
            let element = document.getElementById(image.id);
            element.classList.add('opacity-0');
            element.classList.add('scale-125');
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }, image.duration);
        }
    }, [images])

    return (
        <div id="header" className="relative h-full bg-gray-900 flex justify-center items-center px-16 overflow-hidden">
        <h1 className="bg-black text-gray-200 font-bold text-5xl sm:text-8xl md:text-9xl text-center z-10"></h1>
        {
            images.map((element, index) => {
                return <img key={index} id={element.id} src={element.image} style={{top: element.top, right: element.right}} className={"imageRRSS absolute filter blur-sm w-auto h-" + element.height + "/6 w-auto transform transition-transform-opacity duration-" + element.duration}/>
            })
        }
    </div>
    )
}
```

What it does is to add every 50 miliseconds a new object to the state array **images** that contains the properties of the image to add.

After each addition, as it is a state variable, React re-renders the mapping of the component inside of the return:

```
        {
            images.map((element, index) => {
                return <img key={index} id={element.id} src={element.image} style={{top: element.top, right: element.right}} className={"imageRRSS absolute filter blur-sm w-auto h-" + element.height + "/6 w-auto transform transition-transform-opacity duration-" + element.duration}/>
            })
        }
```

And also it goes to the useEffect and adds the cool animation and, when the animations ends, it deletes the  tag from the HTML:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(images.length > 0) {
            let image = images[images.length - 1];
            let element = document.getElementById(image.id);
            element.classList.add('opacity-0');
            element.classList.add('scale-125');
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }, image.duration);
        }
    }, [images])
```

However, the render just occurs when I interact with the browser.

This is how I understand what it's happening. However, something is clearly wrong as it's not working as expected.

Anybody knows what it's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. The problem was with React applying tailwind effects instantly in the element. I just added the onLoad event to the component instead of ussing useEffect and it works perfectly.